# Combine 2 datasets in SSRS; each dataset coming from a different datasource

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to do a union of reports coming out of 2 separate datasets using "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Report Builder 3.0". The problem is each dataset comes from a different datasource/server. One of the solution was to use the concept of “linked servers”, but we have been suggested not to use the same. So, can you please suggest another possible way out.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "union of reports"? Do you mean combine the two DataSets in one table? Or combine two existing RDL files? If you literally want to create a report based on two existing ones you could just add the two as subreports to a new master report and call it done.

Comment: The last suggestion "add the two as subreports to a new master report" might just work for me.Thanks. Will keep you posted with the results of my effort.

Comment: OK, thanks, let me know, and if it's suitable I will post as an answer to help future users, too.